# How to fix the bad fomatting of table here?

Tags: html, angularjs

The table is getting mis-alligned due to which content is not getting properly displayed.

Comment: Somehow the code is not complete. Can you include until </table>?

Comment: I have done it. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding css below

```
table td {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Your Welcome mate

Comment: this breaks the word as well from the middle. Can't I make sure that the long words move to the next line itself?